# Using a key modifier with blender modal

Tags: python, modal-dialog, operator-keyword, blender, bpy

does anyone know how to make a modal do something different if i have a key held? 
This is what i have at the moment:

```
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE': 
            if event.type == 'LEFT_SHIFT' and event.value == 'PRESS':
                self.value = (event.mouse_region_x - self.mouse_x_initial)
                print(self.value)

            self.value = event.mouse_region_x - self.mouse_x_initial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`event`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Event.html) parameter has boolean properties for `ctrl`, `alt`, `shift` and `oskey`. Test these to know if one of the keys is being held at the time of the event.

```
def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
        if event.ctrl:
            print('Ctrl is down')
        if event.shift:
            print('shift is down')
        if event.alt:
            print('alt is down')
    elif event.type == 'ESC':
        return {'CANCELLED'}
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

As the boolean properties don't distinguish between left and right keys, you would need to keep a record of the previous event and also check that to know which action to take if you wanted them to work differently.

Comment: and what if you users to press two non ctrl/alt/shift/oskey keys at the same time ?